# Creating a simple PHP Image Upload within a Form

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

I am working on a simple Image upload form, with a place for people to add comments and other details. So far i have reached this code.

Problem: When i run this, the file which i upload gets to the directory fine, but the data in the form isn't written to the database.

```
<?php
//$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","Login","password","DBname");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_fname=$_POST['fname'][$key];
        $file_Lname=$_POST['lanem'][$key];
        $file_email=$_POST['email'][$key];
        $file_school=$_POST['school'][$key];
        $file_comment=$_POST['comment'][$key];
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];


        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }



        $query = "INSERT INTO sameplTable(`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`school`,`comment`,`filename`) VALUES
        ('$fname','$lname','$email','$school','$comment','$filename')";




        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;
            }
            mysql_query($query);
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    Value1: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Value2: <input type="text" name="Lname"><br>
    Value3: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Value4: <input type="text" name="school"><br>
    Value5: <input type="text" name="comment"><br>

    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: just want to point out, one of your expected insert variable is `$Fname` but what you have is `$file_fname`.

Comment: @tradyblix That's actually the issue for *every* expected insert variable, causing nothing to actually be inserted.  Also, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection, and the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  Instead use PDO or MySQLi, and use prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It was just a typo on my side.

Comment: even after fixing that and running. It still the same. I get my file upload, but nothing in the DB.

Comment: Your query's column list has 6 columns, whereas the `VALUES` have a length of 7.  I'm not sure if this would prevent the query from working, but it's definitely something to fix.

Comment: You should echo `mysql_error()` after the query to see what the error is.

Comment: i tried mysql_error() and it returned nothing. So i am not sure what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add [] after input's names other than type=file. So there will be no $key for the POST array.

Comment: I don't get it, can you be a bit more explicit.

Comment: Using [] after input's name suppose that you will have several same kind inputs w/ same name and you can access it's values using foreach on server side. Values of SomeName[] will be passed to server as array. Now look at your HTML - you're using [] for files inputs but not for text inputs. But on server side you're trying to access POST variables as it would be a multidimensional array ($file_fname = $_POST["fname"][$key]) while it is not.